# Dividing the space with vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: spacing

I wanna do something like image below :
[image]

but I have no idea how to do it! Is there any package that could help? What is the best way to do something like this?

Comment: I would do it with a table, using the `\cmidrule` command from `booktabs`, and using `\multirow` for the left column

Comment: @Bernard
could you pleaaaaaase wrtie a simple full working example ? for left algortihm just write A and for algorithms just write b and c.

Answer (score 1):

A nested `tabular` could be used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l|l@{}}
    A &
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      b\\
      \midrule
      c
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

`\midrule` from package `booktabs` also takes care of the vertical spacing around it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X} & \\ \multirow{26}{=}{\lipsum[14] }& \lipsum[12] \\
 \addlinespace[2ex] \cmidrule(lr{1em}){2-2}\addlinespace
  & \lipsum[12] \\
 &
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]